# Database Error: NameError: name 'db' is not defined. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

On the web I found [this illustration](https://www.python4networkengineers.com/posts/python-intermediate/create_a_tkinter_gui_with_sqlite_backend/) to create a database with gui with Tkinter.  Everything ok, except when I enter the data and click on the Add button. I'm getting:
`NameError: name 'db' is not defined`

I think what I am wrong is nonsense in this part of the code. What am I doing wrong?

[Here is my code uploaded](https://www.online-python.com/BDXIt7cadQ) su un editor online. I am writing it here because it is too long to enter. I am new and having difficulty with StackOverflow. If we can figure out the error, I'll update the question with the code I'm wrong.

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('/home/dekstop/db.db')
cur = conn.cursor()


class Database:
    def __init__(self, db):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()
        self.cur.execute(
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS routers (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, hostname text, brand text, ram integer, flash integer)")
        self.conn.commit()

    def fetch(self, hostname=''):
        self.cur.execute(
        "SELECT * FROM routers WHERE hostname LIKE ?", ('%'+hostname+'%',))
        rows = self.cur.fetchall()
        return rows

    def fetch2(self, query):
        self.cur.execute(query)
        rows = self.cur.fetchall()
        return rows

    def insert(self, hostname, brand, ram, flash):
        self.cur.execute("INSERT INTO routers VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
                     (hostname, brand, ram, flash))
        self.conn.commit()

    def remove(self, id):
        self.cur.execute("DELETE FROM routers WHERE id=?", (id,))
        self.conn.commit()

    def update(self, id, hostname, brand, ram, flash):
        self.cur.execute("UPDATE routers SET hostname = ?, brand = ?, ram = ?, flash = ? WHERE id = ?",
                     (hostname, brand, ram, flash, id))
        self.conn.commit()

    def __del__(self):
    self.conn.close()
```

Comment: "*when I enter the data and click on the Add button*" What method does this "*add button*" fire? On what line does the resulting stack trace indicate that the error is occurring?

Comment: That error could not have come from this code.

Comment: @esqew I changed the order of the code with respect to that proposed by the site, because some things had to be written before, otherwise other errors were generated. So the lines of code have a different order. I noticed that if I click on each Add, Remove, Update, Clear button I always get the same error (but with a different line of code). The error is always NameError: name 'db' is not defined. I speculated that the error could be that piece of code I posted in the question, maybe I was wrong.

Comment: @TimRoberts So have I linked the database well with "conn" and "cur" in relation to def __init __ (self, db)? If so, then the error will be elsewhere. If you open the question link, all the code is there. Can you help me please? Here is my code uploaded https://www.online-python.com/BDXIt7cadQ. I am writing it here because it is too long to enter. I am new and having difficulty with StackOverflow. If we can figure out the error, I'll update the question with the code I'm wrong.

Comment: @CarryOnWaywardSon96 That still doesn't answer my questions: what method does the button fire? What line number does your error message indicate the error is being thrown on?

Comment: @CarryOnWaywardSon96 "*If you open the question link, all the code is there.*" Please include all code relevant to the issue at hand **in the body of your question**, per [ask] - If "*it is too long to enter*", you should look to reduce it to meet the guidelines outlined on creating a [mre], instead of posting it elsewhere. External links tend to change or break entirely over time, after which questions relying on them do not provide any value to future visitors to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('/home/dekstop/db.db')
cur = conn.cursor()


class Database:
    def __init__(self, db):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()
        self.cur.execute(
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS routers (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, hostname text, brand text, ram integer, flash integer)")
        self.conn.commit()
        ...
```

Right away, you can see a problem there.  You have `conn` and `curr` defined outside the class and inside.  It seems clear that the rest of your code expects `db` to be an instance of the Database class.  So you need:

```
import sqlite3

class Database:
    ... same as always ...

db = Database('/home/dekstop/db.db')
```

and you need to do that before any of the code that refers to `db`.

Comment: Should I delete "conn =" and "cur ="? I have not understood. However I have tried both ways, but I always get the same error as before

Comment: Yes.  You want the `Database` object to be the only one that manages the database..  Please note where I said that you have to create the `db` global before you use it.

Comment: But in def __init __ (self, db), it says self.conn and self.cur. Isn't that an important thing sorry?

Comment: Yes, those are the ones you want.  The ones you DON'T want are at the global level.

Answer (score 0):

assigned variable DB not defined. so it raises an error

```py
def add_router():
    if brand_text.get() == '' or hostname_text.get() == '' or ram_text.get() == '' or flash_text.get() == '':
        messagebox.showerror('Required Fields', 'Please include all fields')
        return
    db.insert(hostname_text.get(), brand_text.get(),
              ram_text.get(), flash_text.get())
    clear_text()
    populate_list()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I replaced the code you wrote me. The error is still there. I noticed that if I click on each Add, Remove, Update, Clear button I always get the same error (but with a different line of code). The error is always NameError: name 'db' is not defined

Comment: sorry for not mention the above code  taken from the illustration that mentioned db variable was not declared before that but the actual issue of how to connect SQL without hostname or db input will not work any dB actions show the same error for all